# Is an orthogonal matrix necessarily a permutation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, permutation-matrices

Is an orthogonal matrix necessarily a permutation matrix?

I believe the answer is no as a permutation matrix is a special case of an orthogonal matrix, but I am having a trouble finding a counterexample. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: Permutation matrices do not have any negative entries. Now consider a diagonal matrix.

Comment: and consider the rotation around some axe in dimension $\ge 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Permutation matrices have only $0$ or $1$ entries.

Orthogonal matrices have columns that are orthogonal unitary vectors.

We can well have orthogonal unitary vectors with entries different from $0$ and $1$. Can you find a simple example in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Or indeed in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: Can $ A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\1&-1\\
\end{bmatrix} $ and $ B = \frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix}
2&-2&1\\1&2&2\\2&1&-2\\
\end{bmatrix} $ be simple examples (orthogonal matrices that are not permutation matrices)?

Comment: yes they are good examples.